# Trying to update/create a navigation property using an Editor Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I must say that I'm quite new to MVC and that last time I've wrote C# code was ... about 4 years ago :)

This is the scenario:

"Shops"

- ShopID
- Name
- (other stuff)
- CityID

"Cities"

- CityID
- Name
- (other stuff)

"Shop" table has a "City" navigation property

I've created a "City" editor template in my MVC 3 project.
This template uses jQuery to find and fill a hidden field with the CityID.

My Shop form (shared with the Edit and Create actions) uses Html.EditorFor(model => model.City) for the City navigation property, rather than using the CityID column.

Well, the bottom line is that id doesn't work, as the controller is trying to update an incomplete City object:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into
>   column 'Name', table
>   'C:\USERS\ANDREA\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL
>   STUDIO
>   2010\PROJECTS\INCONSEGNA\INCONSEGNA\APP_DATA\INCONSEGNA.MDF.dbo.Cities';
>   column does not allow nulls. INSERT
>   fails. The statement has been
>   terminated.

Fair enough, I'm not returning a complete "City" object, but actually, what I need is just the CityID element: the rest is useless, or must be retrieved by the editor template (something that, as far as I can see, can't be done).

Honestly, I would prefer to use and editor template just for the CityID column of the Shops's table (or other tables that will have the same column).
This would mean that I have to create an editor template for a generic "int" type and that I have to explicitly declare which editor template I want to use when calling Html.EditorFor(): I'd rather prefer to let MVC find out that, for the CityID column (of type int), a custom editor template called "City" or even "CityID" must be used: that's why I've attempted to use the navigation property's "City" type.

Any advice?

Comment: I've forgot to mention that my editor template actually needs a "City" object, as it must show the "Name" property/column, when I already have a "CityID" value in the Shop object.

For instance, ShopID=1 is an existing record that has CityID=2 that matches the City "Rome". When I edit the existing Shop record, my editor template must show "Rome".

Answer (score 0):

In five months I've realized how silly was my question, but at that time I didn't have enough knowledge to understand how to properly work with Entity Framework and MVC.

I think I can answer my own question saying that I'm not supposed to create editor templates for a navigation property, when I can freely work with the entity's property related to the foreign key and, if I need add to the ViewModel (or the ViewData) all the data I need to show a dropdown list (see late).

In this case the foreign key would be CityID. When I call the Html.EditorFor() I can specify there which template (e.g. "CitySelector", or whatever I want) I must use (maybe I can even use data annotation in the ViewModel: I don't know about that).

The EditorTemplate would be a partial view called "CitySelector", in the EditorTemplates folder: there I can display a dropdown list or, even better, an autocomplete textbox (jQuery).
The jQuery solution would be the best approach to show a list of cities, without loading all of them in the ViewModel/ViewData.

Hope to have properly answered my own question :)